# how to show confirmation dialogue box on mobile back button in android app?

Tags: android

I want to set confirmation dialogue box when user press back button of mobile. There should be asked from user that "Do you want to exit?".

Comment: You could add an AlertDialog and then call MainActivity.finish() when they click the correct button.

Comment: okay i will use the AlertDialog but how i will attach it with mobile back button click. I am not getting this thing.

Comment: I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        showDialog();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Then add this below:

```
public void showPauseDialog() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(ExerciseActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //leave activity
                    this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do nothing
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Back button should take you to previous activity. When you reach your last activity (most probably the one which is launched when app starts) you need to show an alert asking user if they want to logout.

Add this in your Launching activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        promptUserForLogout();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void promptUserForLogout() {
    final AlertDialog logoutOption = new AlertDialog(this) {
    };
    logoutOption.setTitle("Logout");
    logoutOption.setMessage("Do you want to log out?");
    logoutOption.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface arg0, final int arg1) {
            logoutOption.dismiss();
        }
    });
    logoutOption.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface arg0, final int arg1) {
            logoutOption.dismiss();
            // Call logout API or take your logout action
        }
    });
    logoutOption.show();
}
```